# Installing Laravel in a new GIT branch leaves vendor folder in master

Tags: php, git, laravel, github

I am starting a fresh build of an existing non-Laravel project so I've created an orphan branch off my master, removed existing files and installed Laravel.

The problem is that when I switch back to my master branch, the vendor and storage directories (and files) persist in my local master branch, and are showing up as ready to be staged and committed.

I was under the assumption that any files, folders, etc that are created in the new branch, would not exists when switching branches.

[image]

Comment: Are they already in the git branch? Can you `git rm -rf` to remove them from version tracking?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy There were not in the master branch, no. When I installed Laravel I had the 'fresh' branch checked out. So I was surprised to see the vendor files waiting to be staged when I switched to 'master'

Comment: Are those files `ignored`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, they are yes, in the new branch. They shouldn't even exist in the master though. That is what is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: That's truly odd.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy as long as I'm not the only baffled. I am pretty sure this shouldn't be happening, and it sounds like you are too.  I wonder if the checkout between master and fresh just takes forever locally that it ends up leaving the files behind... but that doesn't sound right either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vendor directory is in the `.gitignore` in your fresh branch, so those files are not tracked by git. They are not added to the repo, and do not wish to be.

When you switch branches, git is not going to touch any files for which it is not tracking. So, when you switch to master, it will not delete the vendor files, as git is not tracking them.

Now when you're on master, your `.gitignore` in master probably does not ignore the vendor directory, so your master branch sees those files as new files ready to be checked in. Add the vendor directory to the `.gitignore` in your master branch, and they'll stop pestering you.

Comment: Even though the vendor files were not created in the main branch? This fresh branch is an orphan of the master which I deleted everything and started building the Laravel project from scratch. As I understood it, I could add remove and change files in one branch and it would not be tracked in the other.

Comment: @eht That's the thing; the vendor files are not tracked in the other branch. That's what git is telling you: "these files aren't tracked, git add to track them?" If git deleted files it wasn't tracking, it would have no way to get them back. So, if you switch from `fresh` to `master`, and git deletes the vendor files, and then switch from `master` back to `fresh`, git would have no way to get those files back, as it doesn't know anything about them. I don't know your situation, but it sounds like it would be more appropriate to have a separate repository, instead of just a separate branch.